# Star/Point based Image Registration

Tags: c, image-processing

I am developing an application that stacks multiple frames captured from a CCD camera. The frames are meant to be "aligned" or registered before stacking them. The initial aim is to ask the user for the relevant control points and then figure out if the frames need rotation and/or translation. Eventually, perhaps in the next version, I'd like to be able to detect the stars and cross-reference them in all the frames automatically.

My question is, is there a library that I can employ to register these images i.e. translate and/or rotate? I am using Xcode on Lion and would really prefer a library meant for Cocoa but anything written in C would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

A tracking library such as [libmv](http://code.google.com/p/libmv/) might work for this, it sounds like a tracking application.